# ¿Como cargar contenido dinámico de javascript en un modal?

Tags: javascript

El código Javascript está en el siguiente enlace: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xMrH1XCK4l5RqmO7TWMI7yE4miCSe-k6

cómo cargar contenido  dinámico en un modal  generado con Bootstrap. La idea es que al abrir el modal se ejecute la animación creada toda en javascript, he revisado tutoriales y documentación pero no he logrado hacer que genere el contenido, tampoco me genera error, simplemente aparece el body del modal en blanco.

He intentado con algo así: Pero no se ha logrado el objetivo.

```css
html,
body {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#progressbar {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 666;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.4/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js'></script>
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xMrH1XCK4l5RqmO7TWMI7yE4miCSe-k6

Comment: Hola Angie cuales son las animaciones que quieres ponerle al modal ? veo que estas utilizando `#myModal` y el id de tu modal es `#exampleModal`

Comment: @IsraelGonzález, la animación está en este enlace: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xMrH1XCK4l5RqmO7TWMI7yE4miCSe-k6. Si, reemplacé #myModal con #exampleModal pero no funciona, toda la animación prácticamente está sólo en javascript, el html solo tiene el modal e invoca el archivo .js